# How to solve HTML5 validation error on fb-like box?

Tags: html, w3c-validation, facebook-likebox

How to solve this HTML 5 validation error related to Facebook like button?

Here is the text from validation engine:

> Line 3170, column 261: Element name `fb:like-box` cannot be represented as XML 1.0.
>
> ```
> …rue" border_color="" stream="false" header="false" height="260" ></fb:like-box>
> ```

Here is the code on Line 3170:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/fburlhere" width="250" show_faces="true" border_color="" stream="false" header="false" height="260" ></fb:like-box>
```

Just after this error, there is also another error which reads:

> Element `fb:like-box` not allowed as child of element `div` in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

referring to the same line number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The markup are dynamically placed/generated from Facebook itself. You cannot control them, the way you want. But there is a HTML5 version of the Like Box, you can use instead.

When you are generating the code for the like-box. You will get an option like[image: Facebook HTML5 like-box]
[[Source]](http://www.technostarry.com/web/html5-code-for-facebook-like-box-plugin/)