# Validation error on HTML5: "Element name fb:like cannot be represented as XML 1.0."

Tags: html, facebook-like, w3c-validation

My page has following code:

```html
 <div class="link-social-follow">
    <fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/testingPage" 
             send="false" 
             layout="button_count"
             width="80" 
             show_faces="false">       
   </fb:like>              
 </div>
```

But when the site is ran on W3C validator, the following error is notified:

> Warning: Element name `fb:like` cannot be represented as XML 1.0.

Comment: Check out this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988981/how-to-solve-html5-validation-error-on-fb-like-box

And this too:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve HTML5 Validation error on fb-like box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988981/how-to-solve-html5-validation-error-on-fb-like-box)